# service ecs-service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

This error happens sporadically, but when it happens, it blocks other events in the service, like scaling.

ERROR:

```
service ecs-service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance xxx has insufficient CPU units available. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section.
```

I checked AWS docs:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-container-instance-requirement-error/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-event-messages.html#service-event-messages-1

They don't provide enough information.

This is the most relevant info on my Task Definition and Task

```
Network mode: bridge
Compatibilities: EXTERNAL, EC2

Task size:
  Memory: 1024
  CPU: 1024

Container definitions:
  Hard/Soft memory limits: 1024/--
  CPU units: 1024
```

Is there a way to fix this and avoid these intermittent failures?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is very clearly saying none of the EC2 instances in your cluster have enough CPU available to run this task, based on the tasks already running on those EC2 servers.

You could either configure a capacity provider on your ECS cluster that would add more EC2 instances to your cluster as needed, or you could switch from EC2 deployments to Fargate, which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Thanks, Mark B. Yes. And that happened when the service was adding EC2 instances and went from 1 instance to 3 instances, that's why I don't understand.

Comment: Does it not try to place the task again after a little bit? I assume this is just telling you that it failed, and is the reason the auto-scaling is happening, at which point ECS will try again.

Comment: Thanks again, Mark! No... When that happens (that doesn't happen all the time) the service gets stuck in that event.